# Override Wishlist view.phtml from custom module not working

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, view.phtml

I tried to override wishlist view.phtml which loaded at customer account page like this:

> app/code/Test/Salesman/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Test_Salesman::wishlist/view.phtml </argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock> 
</page>
```

> app/code/Test/Salesman/view/frontend/templates/wishlist/view.phtml

```
<h1> SUCCESS </h1>
```

but it always shows the original phtml file

Comment: Have you tried removing the space before the closing argument tag? Just in case.

Answer (score 1):

There is 1 issue with your code.
space in argument statement.

Please use below code its working fine in my system, I have tested this.

> update file
>   app/code/Test/Salesman/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Test_Salesman::wishlist/view.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock> 
  </body>    
  </page>
```

if its help dont forgot accept & upvote ;)

Comment: Yogesh, why we need insert `update` handle in this xml? Already there is `update` in standard layout `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml`

Comment: &Evgeny Levinsky you are right this not required i have updated answer.

Comment: @Yogesh it's still not working

Comment: @Shell Which version of magento2 you are using.

Comment: @ShellSuite also try with updated answer.

Comment: @Yogesh version 2.2 with Porto Theme

Comment: this issue arise due to custom theme. in default magento 2 theme its working fine. Please check your theme configuration.